# If -multiple- elements are not in a list, then

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently am trying to create a sort of blacklist of some undesired items within a list of many other items.

I currently have this very ugly conditional statement that works correctly, but I find it's tedious to add to, and looks bad. I have to add to it manually, I'm finding this is an issue because I want to add to the blacklist based on a function in my code, so manually adding will not suffice anymore.

I would like "NEW" to be in the title of the desired item, and all the conditionals following are "not in blacklist", which seems very repetitive.

```
if "NEW" in lst[i][0] and "Pears" not in lst[i][0] and "Strawberries" not in lst[i][0] and "Oranges" not in lst[i][0] and "Cherries" not in lst[i][0] and "Plums" not in lst[i][0] and "Nectarines" not in lst[i][0] and "raspberries" not in lst[i][0] and "Apples" not in lst[i][0]:
```

I would like to find a way to simply create a blacklist list, and have python proceed if any items in the blacklist are not found in another list.

I have already tried creating a blacklist list and tried:

```
lst = ['Broccoli', 'Chicken', 'Oranges', 'Apples', 'Squash', ' Salmon']

blacklist = ['Pears', 'Strawberries', 'Oranges']

#My actual lists are much longer

for i in range(len(lst)):
    for blacklisteditem in blacklist:
        if blacklisteditem in lst[i]:
            print("This item is not blacklisted, proceeding..")
        else:
            print("This item was blacklisted")
```

But this returns:

```
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item is not blacklisted, proceeding..
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
This item was blacklisted
```

Clearly not the objective here. There must be some solution I'm overlooking, could anyone help me?
I just want to apply the logic of "if x not in lst:", but I want x to be multiple items, preferably those in a list, or perhaps a string I could append to?

I basically need to be able to append to this blacklist some way or another instead of having to manually edit the script, because I want my program to be able to add additional entries. If this involves somehow appending to the long, ugly conditional, then that's fine, as long as it works.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, you are masking the built-in type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your blacklist a set, and test if there is no intersection with your list (the set is *disjoint*):

```
blacklist = {'Pears', 'Strawberries', 'Oranges'}
if blacklist.isdisjoint(lst):
    print("This item is not blacklisted, proceeding..")
else:
    print("This item was blacklisted")
```

The [`set.isdisjoint()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) returns `True` only if there are no elements in common:

```
>>> lst = ['Broccoli', 'Chicken', 'Oranges', 'Apples', 'Squash', ' Salmon']
>>> blacklist = {'Pears', 'Strawberries', 'Oranges'}
>>> blacklist.isdisjoint(lst)
False
>>> blacklist.isdisjoint(['Broccoli', 'Chicken', 'Apples', 'Squash', ' Salmon'])
True
```

Your attempt didn't wait until all blacklisted items had been tested; you print for *every single element* you test. You need to wait until your for loop is complete, before drawing the conclusion that none of the `blacklist` elements appeared.